# How to delete a character from a string in console

Tags: c#

```
using System; 

class Strng { 

    // Main Method 
    public static void Main() 
    { 

        // define string 
        String str = "Some_String"; 

        Console.WriteLine("Given String : " + str); 

        // delete from index 5 to end of string 
        Console.WriteLine("New String1 : " + str.Remove(5)); 

        // delete character from index 8 to end of string 
        Console.WriteLine("New String2 : " + str.Remove(8)); 
    } 
}
```

The above works with the given input but I want to give input dynamically and remove a character from given string dynamically

Comment: Remove a character based on what condition?

Comment: based on the input character from the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to read dynamically a string and a character to replace.

You can do this with the use of `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()`

Implementing the following into your main method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a string:");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter a character to remove:");
string rs = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
//Assuming if they enter 'a' you want to remove both 'a' AND 'A':
string rsUpCase = rs.ToUpper();
string rsLoCase = rs.ToLower();
s = s.Replace(rsUpCase,"");     
s = s.Replace(rsLoCase,"");
Console.WriteLine(s);

//Input:
//Aardvarks are boring creatures
//Result:
//rdvrks re boring cretures
```

Will allow a user to enter a string dynamically (not hard-coded) and remove any character taking advantage of the `Replace` function - also demonstrated is the use of upper/lower case to determine if you want both variants of a character to be removed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I use Remove() instead?

Comment: @Shiva_Kishore for a specific instance of a character? No - Remove is used to *remove* a portion of a string not a specific instance of a character. You could get an index of a character then use remove to remove it but that's convaluted

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to give a reputation for your answer but sorry I am not eligible to vote you.

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer at any reputation - are you clicking the tick symbol by the vote arrows?

Comment: Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct question is how to read from console.

You can use `Console.Read()` and `Console.ReadLine()`.

First ask for the string, and then ask for the index to remove, if this is what you mean with *dynamically*

This is a MSDN Example about `Read`

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string m1 = "\nType a string of text then press Enter. " +
                "Type '+' anywhere in the text to quit:\n";
    string m2 = "Character '{0}' is hexadecimal 0x{1:x4}.";
    string m3 = "Character     is hexadecimal 0x{0:x4}.";
    char ch;
    int x;
//
    Console.WriteLine(m1);
    do  
        {
        x = Console.Read();
        try 
            {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
               {
               Console.WriteLine(m3, x);
               if (ch == 0x0a) 
                   Console.WriteLine(m1);
               }
            else
               Console.WriteLine(m2, ch, x);
            }
        catch (OverflowException e) 
            {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Value read = {1}.", e.Message, x);
            ch = Char.MinValue;
            Console.WriteLine(m1);
            }
        } while (ch != '+');
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you, please mark the question as solved and take some minutes to read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Yes, but am waiting for other alternate answers,and I did not find by intended answer